# How to modify the content of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

I have some nested lists and I want to be able to modify them having the indexes of where the modification would take place.

One example of such lists is:

```py
l2 = ['Node_50',
      ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']],
      ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]
     ]
```

I then have a new list of elements and a list cointaing the indexes

```py
lnew = ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']
indexes = [1, 3]
```

I would like to get a function that replaces the element of the list at the indexes given by the newlist of values. The function would have to do that (for this example):

```py
l2[1][3] = lnew
```

The lists can have any number of nested lists so the length of indexes may change.
The fucntion would need to work for any nested list and for any number of indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shorter is :

```
l2 = ['Node_50',
      ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']],
      ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]
     ]


lnew = ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']
indexes = [1, 3]


def set_deep(root, indexes, value):

    for x in indexes[:-1]:
        root = root[x]
    root[indexes[-1]] = value


set_deep(l2, indexes, lnew)


print(l2)
```

Thinking about it, the feature list[iterable] should be added to Python.
I think actualy numpy supports list[list] notation?

Answer (score 2):

I think that [user8426627](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419928/98057) has already given a great answer but if you prefer a functional style, you could do something like this:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import getitem
>>> reduce(getitem, indexes[:-1], l2)[indexes[-1]] = lnew
>>> l2
['Node_50',
  ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']],
  ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function, just assign the new list to the desired position and it will replace the previous value.

```
l2 = ['Node_50',
       ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']],
       ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]
      ]
lnew = ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']
```

before

```
l2[1][3]
```

returns

```
['Node_20']
```

then replace it

```
l2[1][3] = lnew
```

after

```
l2[1][3]
```

returns

```
['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']
```

This can also be done with a **function**

```
def myFUN(LIST, newLIST, indexes):
    i,j = indexes
    if i >= len(LIST):
        print("list index (" + str(i) + ") out of range")
        return
    elif j >= len(LIST[i]):
        print("list index (" + str(j) + ") out of range")
        return
    else:
        LIST[i][j] = newLIST
        return LIST
```

now

```
myFUN(l2, lnew, indexes)
```

returns

```
['Node_50', ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']], ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
```

but

```
myFUN(l2, lnew, (4,1))
```

returns

```
list index (4) out of range
```

and

```
myFUN(l2, lnew, (1,25))
```

returns

```
list index (25) out of range
```

**Keep the original list unchanged**

For python3

```
def myFUN(LIST, newLIST, indexes):
    res = LIST.copy()
    i,j = indexes
    if i >= len(LIST):
        print("list index (" + str(i) + ") out of range")
        return
    elif j >= len(LIST[i]):
        print("list index (" + str(j) + ") out of range")
        return
    else:
        res[i][j] = newLIST
        return res
```

in python 2 use `res = LIST[:]` or `res=list(LIST)`. Now

```
myFUN(l2, lnew, indexes)
```

returns

```
['Node_50', ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_1', 'Node_40', 'Node_17']], ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
```

but l2 remains unaltered

```
l2
```

returns

```
['Node_50', ['Node_48', 'Node_23', ['Node_12', 'Node_3'], ['Node_20']], ['Node_22', ['Node_44'], ['Node_7', 'Node_40']]]
```

Comment: Not really, let me clarify:  I know how to do it for one specific example, what I would want is a function that would do that but with any original list, any newlist and any indexes list (it can have many values)

Comment: Do you know how to generalize the same thing?

Comment: @Daniel Casasampera, how about now?

Comment: Not really imagine a different list2 with indexes = [1, 3, 5 ,4, 3, ...]

Comment: so you want to modify l2 by indexes 1,3,5,4,3? Just add a for loop inside the function to iterate over all the indexes until it gets to the last one. You should consider adding a mcve (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can fully address your problem

Comment: myFUN is so wrong, since python throes index exception on its own and guess the dud wahted to have loop in there